# npm install browserify stuck

Tags: npm-install

When I tried to install `browserify`, it got stuck on installation. Here is the code and logs:

```
$ npm install --save --no-optionals --verbose browserify
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ 'D:\\Software\\Matrix\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm verb cli   'D:\\Software\\Matrix\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
npm verb cli   'install',
npm verb cli   '--save',
npm verb cli   '--no-optionals',
npm verb cli   '--verbose',
npm verb cli   'browserify' ]
npm info using npm@5.5.1
npm info using node@v9.3.0
npm verb npm-session dac291176e74610d
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/browserify 317ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/JSONStream 59ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/browserify-zlib 150ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/assert 153ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/browser-pack 169ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/browser-resolve 173ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/cached-path-relative 176ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/buffer 184ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/constants-browserify 185ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/concat-stream 187ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/console-browserify 189ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/crypto-browserify 162ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/domain-browser 91ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/deps-sort 98ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/has 161ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/https-browserify 151ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/events 170ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/htmlescape 173ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/duplexer2 207ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/insert-module-globals 192ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/glob 233ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/os-browserify 139ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/labeled-stream-splicer 195ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/module-deps 192ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/path-browserify 160ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/parents 172ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/process 158ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/querystring-es3 164ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/read-only-stream 150ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream 104ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/shasum 134ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/stream-browserify 125ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/shell-quote 136ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/stream-http 121ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/subarg 108ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/string_decoder 145ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/syntax-error 104ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/timers-browserify 115ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/tty-browserify 109ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/url 87ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/util 82ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/vm-browserify 121ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/inherits 35ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/combine-source-map 24ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/umd 43ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/inline-source-map 52ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/convert-source-map 55ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.memoize 63ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/jsonparse 84ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/resolve 29ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/pako 33ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/base64-js 33ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/ieee754 34ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/typedarray 27ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/isarray 18ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/date-now 42ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/create-ecdh 47ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/create-hmac 65ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/browserify-sign 68ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/public-encrypt 69ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/create-hash 71ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/browserify-cipher 78ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/pbkdf2 78ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/diffie-hellman 81ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/randombytes 109ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/randomfill 115ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/browserify-aes 34ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/browserify-des 58ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/evp_bytestokey 59ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/buffer-xor 21ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/cipher-base 23ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/ripemd160 26ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/sha.js 29ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/hash-base 26ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/md5.js 19ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/des.js 24ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/minimalistic-assert 21ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/bn.js 31ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/parse-asn1 33ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/browserify-rsa 59ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/elliptic 60ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/brorand 84ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/hash.js 95ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/hmac-drbg 125ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/minimalistic-crypto-utils 126ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/asn1.js 33ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/miller-rabin 33ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/json-stable-stringify 31ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/fs.realpath 73ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch 75ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/function-bind 46ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/lexical-scope 51ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/astw 27ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/acorn 53ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/stream-splicer 21ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/detective 32ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/stream-combiner2 35ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/@browserify%2facorn5-object-spread 138ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/path-platform 80ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/array-reduce 45ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/array-filter 46ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/array-map 45ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/builtin-status-codes 36ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/to-arraybuffer 44ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/querystring 48ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/punycode 52ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/fsevents 68ms
```

The terminal stuck here (right after GET fsevents) forever.
What else can I do?

Comment: Try using https registry `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`

Answer (score 0):

This was also my problem, What I did is that closed the cmd and again started with Admin privileges. Then again started the install and it worked this time.